# Mutliple Signers

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect, docusign-sdk

We have a business case where we have a document that is auto-tagged (text-pattern matching) for two signers. We send the envelope to three recipients. The two auto tagged signers are able to login and sign the envelope, however the envelope does not send back the envelope complete notification in DocuSign Connect.

Is there an account setting so that only the signers that actually have to sign can send the complete notification. We have a few envelopes in this limbo state of not being complete.

We are using the C#SDK/RestAPI to create our envelopes.

Thank you

We have tried submitting an envelope with three signers, and the document only contains auto-tags for two of them. The third signer can access, but has no signing capabilities (as intended). The envelope doesn't fire the completed notification because of this.

Answer (score 0):

Every signer must "act" on an envelope in order for it to be complete.
In your situation. the 3rd signer was intended to only view the envelope then it should not be a signer.
There are other types of recipients based on your requirements.
Two options:

1. CC - this means they'll get a copy, but they don't have to view/open it.
2. MustView - this is a type of recipient **HAS to open** the envelope for it to be complete, but does not have to sign it.

If you change your 3rd recipient to either one of these (and in case #2 that recipient actually opens the envelope) it will be completee and you'll get the complete notifications.